# Customizing Windows Vista Calendar Display

Tags: delphi, calendar, windows-vista, customization, persian

I want to make a program using Delphi, to watch and wait windows vista calendar displays (the two windows that appear bottom right of the screen when you hold or click the mouse on the time in systray), and when they appeared change their contents to make my own calendar (Persian calendar). Is there any way to change the contents of calendar control (SysMonthCal32) with windows messages?

Sample:
[image]

Comment: Depends on what exactly do you mean with *change the contents*. You can use [`macros`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485976(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`messages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485977(v=vs.85).aspx), however I haven't tested if they works for the system caledar control.

Comment: Depend on how far you want to change, you may need to inject a DLL into the Explorer process or subclass the SysMonthCal32 class entirely. Or use a Windows Hook API.

Comment: Er, don't do this. The clock/calendar app belongs to the system.

Comment: @TLama you'd need to run the code in the same process that owns the calendar window

Comment: I don't want to change all system date or all calendar controls on windows, I just want to add a button to switch calender type just on that window between Persian and Gregorian. For example if there where labels for days in calender control I want to enumerate them and change their text temporarily.

Comment: Send a feature request to MS. In the meantime write your own calendar app. Or download one that does what you want. Hacking the system isn't really terribly viable.

Comment: Do you refer to Hijri Shamsi calendar? It is not implemented in Windows 7 and Microsoft isn't willing to implement anything like it. You must use a third-party component for your application.

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera yes, you're right. That's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it. The program must watch for creation of calendar window and then place its own calendar on it using SetParent API function.
You can see the result app in http://www.dihav.com/pghcal/.